# minimum polynomial of $ e^{\frac{2\pi i }{17}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

minimum polynomial of $$ \exp{\dfrac{2\pi i }{17}}$$ I tried by letting $\alpha = \exp{\dfrac{2\pi i }{17}} \iff \alpha^{17} = 1 \iff \alpha^{17} - 1 = 0$ however wolframalpha gives $\dfrac{\alpha^{17}-1}{\alpha - 1}$

Comment: It follows from school algebra (the factor theorem) that $x-1$ is a factor of $x^{17}-1,$ and $e^{2\pi i}$ is not a root of $x-1,$ so $x^{17} - 1$ can't be the minimal polynomial. However, more will be needed to show that the minimal polynomial is actually the quotient after division by $x-1.$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Sorry what do you mean is not a root of $x-1$. as $e^{2\pi i} = 1$ it is a root of $x-1$?

Comment: Oops, a math-texting oversight. I meant "... and $e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{17}}$ is not a root of $x-1,$ so ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the polynomial $x^{17}-1$ is divisible by $x-1$, so the minimum polynomial must be a divisor of $\frac{x^{17}-1}{x-1}$.
Now if you use the substitution $x=y+1$ you get
$$\frac{(y+1)^{17}-1}{y}=y^{16}+17y^{15}+ {17\choose2}y^{14}+...+{17\choose15}y+17$$
that is irreducible by Eisenstein criterion. So also $\frac{x^{17}-1}{x-1}$ is irreducible and therefore it is the minimum polynomial.